# Is there a DOM or CSS property for height or width that XML objects honor

Tags: javascript, css, xml, svg

I am in the process of manipulating the height and width of xml elements in an SVG file. It seems the only way to do this is to alter the height and width attributes. This is because the CSS & DOM properties are not recognised by XML elements.

Are there properties for height and width of XML elements that can be scripted/styled with Javascript/CSS?

EDIT: http://jsfiddle.net/David_Knowles/ZYhSm/

```
<svg>
<!-- shortend -->
<g id="v-bars">
    <rect class="light" x="67" y="0" width="59.858" height="309.522"/>
    <rect class="dark" x="135.021" y="0" width="59.858" height="276.484"/>
    <rect class="light" x="203.041" y="0" width="59.857" height="227.168"/>
    <rect class="dark" x="271.061" y="0" width="59.858" height="201.097"/>
    <rect class="light" x="339.082" y="0" width="59.857" height="140.743"/>
    <rect class="dark" x="407.102" y="0" width="59.857" height="295.851"/>
    <rect class="light" x="475.121" y="0" width="59.859" height="321.301"/>
    <rect class="dark" x="543.143" y="0" width="59.857" height="165.981"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: CSS is certainly compatible with SVG XML. How are you working with the SVG image?

Comment: Sure CSS is compatible, but it's important to know that NOT all CSS is. I'm using inline svg. Added example.

Answer (score 1):

Some things in SVG are modelled as [attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/attindex.html), other things are modelled as [CSS properties](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/propidx.html). HTML is the same, many things in HTML are CSS properties e.g. color, height, width but others are attributes e.g.

```
<select>
  <option value="car">Car</option>
  <option value="van">Van</option>
</select>
```

Here value is an attribute and if you were using jquery you'd get it by calling attr("value")

Equally SVG uses CSS properties sometimes e.g.

```
<rect style="fill: blue"/>
```

One source of confusion is that SVG often maps CSS properties to attributes so that you can set a CSS property using the attribute setting syntax e.g.

```
<rect fill="blue"/>
```

Here setting the fill attribute actually sets the fill CSS property.

height and width are generally attributes in SVG but styles in HTML. jquery assumes that height is a CSS property which is reasonable from its point of view as it was written to make manipulating HTML easier but it means it doesn't work so well with SVG.

Both attributes and CSS properties can be changed via javascript [getAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getAttribute?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/element.getAttribute) gets an attribute and [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.setAttribute?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/element.setAttribute) sets it. You can't generally manipulate something that's an attribute using CSS though.

You can change CSS via javascript by calling element.style.property e.g.

```
element.style.fill="blue";
```

Comment: Thx for all the great info. I would however contend with the very last point; element.style.fill refers to the assignment of a color and not to it's height. You can not set the height with fill, or indeed with style.height for that matter :-)

Comment: Oops I was originally going to use height but then that would be a HTML only example. I have corrected the example to set the fill to a valid colour.